# MongoDB $lookup with $match and $eq, matching value inside array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here are the document bson example. [Mongodb Playground Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SlP1_-2Oalq)

```
db={
  "chats": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6000cb3a7ca86a96c13bada8"),
      "clients": [
        {
          "email": "2222@mail.id",
          "_id": ObjectId("6000cb3a7ca86a96c13bada9"),
          "id": 2222,
          "as": "owner",
          "username": "2222",
          "phonenumber": "1111"
        },
        {
          "email": "1111@mail.id",
          "_id": ObjectId("6000cb3a7ca86a96c13badaa"),
          "id": 1111,
          "as": "user",
          "username": "1111",
          "phonenumber": "1111"
        }
      ],
      "roomId": "6",
      "createdAt": ISODate("2021-01-14T22:52:42.357Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-01-14T22:52:42.357Z"),
      "__v": 0
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6000cb3a7ca86a96c13badab"),
      "status": "SEND",
      "roomId": ObjectId("6000cb3a7ca86a96c13bada8"),
      "text": "Hellw as a user here",
      "senderId": 2222,
      "receiverId": 1111,
      "createdAt": ISODate("2021-01-14T22:52:42.365Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-01-14T22:52:42.365Z"),
      "__v": 0,
      
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("6000cb457ca86a96c13badac"),
      "status": "SEND",
      "roomId": ObjectId("6000cb3a7ca86a96c13bada8"),
      "text": "Hellow I'm onwer too guyy",
      "senderId": 1111,
      "receiverId": 2222,
      "createdAt": ISODate("2021-01-14T22:52:53.596Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-01-14T22:52:53.596Z"),
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to search on array of object joined result in MongoDB using `$match`, `$expr` and `$eq` to search message that has `clients.id =  1111` and `clients.as = "user"` So far I use this query (also present on playground)

```
db.messages.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chats",
      /** $roomId are field from messages*/
      let: {
        roomId: "$roomId"
      },
      /** $_id are field from chats*/
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$roomId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$clients.id",
                    1111
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$clients.as",
                    "user"
                  ]
                },
                
              ],
              
            },
            
          },
          
        },
        
      ],
      as: "chat_room",
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

Is not succeed for now and produce `chat_room: []`, using `{ $eq: ["$_id", "$$roomId"]}` I successfully join the 2 schema, but when I use `$eq` it to search whether `chat_room.clients.id` is `1111` and `chat_room.clients.as` is `user` it only produce blank `chat_room: []`

1. How to find `chat_room.clients.id` is `1111` and `chat_room.clients.as` is `user` ?
2. Could it the query return empty if I search for `chat_room.clients.id` is `1111` and `chat_room.clients.as` is `owner` since there is no `chats` document that has `clients.id = 1111` as an "owner"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct your match conditions,

- user `$elemMatch` for array field conditions

```
db.messages.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "chats",
      let: { roomId: "$roomId" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$roomId"] },
            clients: {
              $elemMatch: {
                id: 1111,
                as: "user"
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

- if you want to select matching element from clients try `$filter` and put your conditions

```
        {
          $addFields: {
            clients: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$clients",
                cond: {
                  $and: [
                    { $eq: ["$$this.id", 1111] },
                    { $eq: ["$$this.as", "user"] }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "chat_room"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IaCVF7p9v9_)

Comment: It shows result (not just blank) if I  search `owner`, `1111` ? Is this the nature of `$lookup` ? Still show the element whether the search return false  https://mongoplayground.net/p/8HSjeSTNCoC

Comment: $elemMatch will match both fields (id, as) in same element, if it does not then it will return blank, yes this is the nature of lookup it will return atleast blank [] array  when result not found, you have to put $match stage after the lookup stage, like `{ $match: { chat_room: { $ne: [] } } }` see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FE0H3BHEo3u)